# Why does the Magento official documentation say that we have to download version 2.3-develop for MFTF (Magento Functional Testing Framework )?

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.3

We use Magento 2.3 for our project.
The url of the official documentation of the functional tests with MFTF (Magento Functional Testing Framework) is https://devdocs.magento.com/mftf/2.3/getting-started.html

According to the official documentation we have to do the installation following these steps:

1) git clone https://github.com/magento/magento2.git

2) cd magento2 /

3) git checkout 2.3-develop
...

Our questions are:

1) Is it necessary to do the "git clone https://github.com/magento/magento2.git" of the official repository? because we have the project downloaded from the url https://magento.com/tech-resources/download and not from Magento 2 github

2) Is it necessary to do the "git checkout 2.3-develop" ??? because our project has version 2.3 instead of the 2.3-develop

Do we need to install the 2.3-develop as a separate project for functional tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to install Magento 2.3,you can use anything.But cloning from github recommended because the contributors in github would fix the Bugs,so you can get better one